Who calculates refund for iOS In-app purchase upgrade
In my application I have 3 types of monthly auto-renewing subscriptions.
Pro      3.99$
Premium  2.99$
Standard 1.99$
A user who is already having a standard subscription plan, plans to upgrade to Premium after 15days of usage. In this case who is responsible for refunding the remaining amount on usage charge.
If its developers responsibility what is the API to use and how to calculate refund.

Apple handles all billing and refunds
